# Access runfiles path in bazel BUILD file

Tags: bazel

I try to write a very simple `cc_test` in Bazel that builds a test runner and hands it the path to a test file as command line argument.

I tried to use the following snippet which seemed to do the trick according to [1](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/testing.html) and [2](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#data).

```
cc_test(
    name = "my_test",
    srcs = [...],
    deps = [...],
    data = [":test_file"],
    args = ["$(location :test_file)"]
)
```

My runner gets a relative path to the testfile, which, however, is not the proper path and the test fails.

This seems to be related to symlink issues with bazel under Windows (http://jayconrod.com/posts/108/writing-bazel-rules--data-and-runfiles), but I cannot believe there is no way to easily achieve what I am trying to.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47856239/runfiles-location-substitution) answer, but I am searching for a purely BUILD-file based solution which doesn't use custom rules (whether this is a proper choice is different question, but I have the feeling that I am just missing something very fundamental here).